# Get all the combinations of 3d array in js

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get all the possible combinations of a 3d array.
I found a lot of answers for one- or two-dimensional arrays with recursive functions but no solution works for a deeper nested array.

The array structure is always the same (three levels), but the length of each level can change.

example code:

```
function getCombinations(arr){
  ...
}

var arr = [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [30, 40]]];
var arr2 = [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [50]], [[400, 500, 600]]];


res = getCombinations(arr);
res2 = getCombinations(arr2);
```

expected outputs:

```
// arr: [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [30, 40]]]
[
    [[100], [10, 30]],
    [[100], [10, 40]],

    [[100], [20, 30]],
    [[100], [20, 40]],

    [[200], [10, 30]],
    [[200], [10, 40]],

    [[200], [20, 30]],
    [[200], [20, 40]],
];

// arr2: [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [50]], [[400, 500, 600]]]
[
    [[100], [10, 50], [400]],
    [[100], [10, 50], [500]],
    [[100], [10, 50], [600]],

    [[100], [20, 50], [400]],
    [[100], [20, 50], [500]],
    [[100], [20, 50], [600]],

    [[200], [10, 50], [400]],
    [[200], [10, 50], [500]],
    [[200], [10, 50], [600]],

    [[200], [20, 50], [400]],
    [[200], [20, 50], [500]],
    [[200], [20, 50], [600]],
];
```

Comment: Have you managed to try out any code yet? If so, it'd be great to see it in this question, that'll help you get some good answers

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.  (**Hint**: you can do this with two uses of a Cartesian product function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own version was similar, although I think my `cartesian` function is a bit simpler.

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined ? [[]] : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const getCombinations = (xss) => 
  cartesian (xss .map (cartesian))


const arr = [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [30, 40]]];
const arr2 = [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [50]], [[400, 500, 600]]];

console .log (JSON .stringify (getCombinations (arr), null, 4))
console .log (JSON .stringify (getCombinations (arr2), null, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

By researching *Cartesian product function*, I get more knowledge to implement a solution

Certesion product function (answered by **viebel** at this question: [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)):

```
function cartesianProduct(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.map(function (x) {
            return b.map(function (y) {
                return x.concat([y]);
            });
        }).reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a.concat(b);
        }, []);
    }, [[]]);
}
```

Nested call for deeper nested arrays:

```
let arr = [[[100, 200]], [[10, 20], [30, 40]]];
let res = cartesianProduct(arr.map(a => cartesianProduct(a)));
```

Thanks a lot to **Scott Sauyet** for the hint in the comments!